# Match partial query string with complete document in elaticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I require to search against documents of small text length added to an index in elasticsearch and want to get search results only if the search query matches any of my document text completely.
E.g.
Let these be two documents added to index.

1.) {
    name: "alpha beta"
}

2.) {
    name: "gamma delta"
}

if the query strings are -

```
1.) "alpha beats beta"

2.) "alpha beats gammma"
```

than first query should return first document as all the tokens of document match as it is. But second query shouldn't return any document as no such documents exist whose all tokens are present in the query string as it is.

NOTE: Result should only be returned if all the tokens of the text filed in document are present in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize the terms by space and write query as below.

```
{
"query": {
 "bool": {
      "should" : [          

           {"match_phrase" : { "name": "alpha"}},
           {"match_phrase" : { "name": "beta"}}
      ],
"minimum_should_match" : 2
 }
},
size:50
}
```

Here "minimum_should_match" : n is key, where n is number of terms.